# How to find intel realsense D400 series on the gesture recognition details?

Tags: intel, realsense

how many gestures can be recognized?
The specific range of gesture recognition?
What are the advantages compared to sr300？

Answer (score 1):

D400 series works only with LibRS2.0, the LibRS2.0 doesn't have gesture recognition MW.

Comment: Will gesture recognition be available in future libRS ?

Comment: No, there won't be MW inside LibRS, you can leverage existing library such as openCV, openNI.